# Insert multiple field values based for a specific id

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, insert

I have a timetable from a teacher. This teacher has his own classes and she should be able to enter his class-topic from the hour in the database.

I am trying to figure out how this is possible.

Here is my problem (code): I have in my teacher html view a field that has different names

```
<td><input type="text" name="classContent_{{ item.content }}"></td>
```

This would be

```
classContent_0
classContent_1
classContent_2
classContent_3
```

So I have different field names for everyone topic (hour)

Now I am getting the timetable data and grouping it by dates(so later the teacher can select the specific day and get the data)

```
$timetable = $administration->timetableDataByUsername($username);

        foreach ($timetable as $item)  {
            foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                $timetableGroupedByDate[$item['date']][$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        var_dump($timetableGroupedByDate);
```

Here is the var dump

```
'2019-05-02' => 
    array (size=9)
      'profile_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'untericht_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'stundenplan_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'inhalt' => null
      'zeit' => string '12:25' (length=5)
      'date' => string '2019-05-02' (length=10)
      'raum_nr' => string '10' (length=2)
      'typ' => string 'schlagzeug' (length=10)
      'content' => int 2
  '2019-06-02' => 
    array (size=9)
      'profile_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'untericht_id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'stundenplan_id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'inhalt' => null 
      'zeit' => string '16:05' (length=5)
      'date' => string '2019-06-02' (length=10)
      'raum_nr' => string '5' (length=1)
      'typ' => string 'trombone' (length=8)
      'content' => int 4
  '2019-06-03' => 
    array (size=9)
      'profile_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'untericht_id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'stundenplan_id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'inhalt' => null
      'zeit' => string '16:45' (length=5)
      'date' => string '2019-06-03' (length=10)
      'raum_nr' => string '10' (length=2)
      'typ' => string 'generell' (length=8)
      'content' => int 5
```

Basically I want to add the

> inhalt

specific field, now it only adds to the bottom of the table.

Here is the main problem: my insert statement

```
    public function addContent($content) {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("
                                        INSERT INTO untericht (inhalt)
                                        VALUE (?)
        ");

        $stmt->execute([$content]);
      }
```

and this is how I call it in the controller:

```
        if (isset($_POST['submitContent'])) {
            $administration->addContent(
                    $_POST['classContent_0']
            );
}
```

Basically when I add something to the first field it gets added to the database, but as a new row. it should however be added for example for the first array where

> inhalt

is empty

How could I best solve this ?

EDIT:

Here is a picture so it makes more sense.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) a database row. Here is an example method:

```
public function updateContent($rowId, $content) {
    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE untericht
                                      SET inhalt = ?
                                      WHERE id = ?");

    $statement ->execute([$content, $rowId]);
}
```

Notice how you need to be able to uniquely identify which row you want to update. I have done that with a `$rowId`. I'm not sure your database table has such a column, but most of the time it is useful to have a column with [a unique auto-incrementing value](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp).

It is not a good idea to check the row where `inhalt` is empty, because that means you are never sure which row will be changed.

Comment: And how do i add this dynamicaly with my sumbit function ?

Comment: @roibubble What is clear is that your HTML form should already have the row id in it. When the form is submitted these ids are part of the submission and can be used to call  the method in my answer. Since the form and submit function are missing, I cannot give more details.

Comment: The submit function is there, maybe i am not understanding something. Sorry.

Comment: @roibubble Ah, yes, but you have multiple rows, I guess you've named the text inputs `classContent_0`, `classContent_1`, and so on. You should replace the `0`, `1`, etc. by the row ids. Do you know about "Auto Increment Values"?

Comment: Yes the id of my table is beeing Auto Incremented, I just can't make the connection to write it into code (doesn't really make sense). I will try and replace the 0 and 1 with the rows ids yes that makes sense.And when i do that how does my Code look in My Controller that addes those values ?

Comment: @roibubble Then on submission you can `foreach` through the `$_POST` array. Check the key. If it starts with the string `"classContent_"` you know the value will be an text input containing the `inhalt` of the row who's id follows after that start string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195534/discussion-between-roibubble-and-kiko-software).

Comment: @roibubble: Sorry, I wasn't behind my computer anymore.